# Can you change the behavior of Out-Default for a script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script with a series of Invoke-Command statements, and each one has code on the end writing out to a file.  Can I simply change the behavior of Out-Default temporarily and clean up my script a little?

```
... | Out-File $LogFile -append
```

[EDIT]
This is on Powershell 2.0

Comment: If you create a command or alias called `Out-Default`, that does what you want it to, will that replace the default `Out-Default`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you?  Yes.

```
filter Out-Default{ $_ | Out-File 'C:\logfile.txt' -append }
```

Now all output will go to the log file by default.  Remove the temporary definition via

```
dir function:\Out-Default | del
```

But this is very hacky, non-obvious, and difficult to maintain, so I would not recommend it.  It would be better to define a simple dedicated logging function, so that you only needed to add `| log` to the relevant lines of the script.  Much better to have a bit of extra code that is obvious to understand, debug, and change, than to add hacks just to "simplify" the code.

Comment: Thanks latkin, that sounds like the best solution.

Comment: Nice. The command for removing the function can be simplified to: `Remove-Item Function:Out-Default`

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't change the way `Out-Default` works, if you have PowerShell 3.0 you can set default parameter values for `Out-File`, doing so will not require you to specify them on the command line:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:FilePath'] = $LogFile
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Append'] = $true


... | Out-File
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot better, but only on v2.0 unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

From "Powershell Cookbook", 2013:

```
<#  
.SYNOPSIS
Adds a new Out-Default command wrapper to store up to 500 elements from
the previous command. This wrapper stores output in the $ll variable.
#>

Set-StrictMode -Version 3

New-CommandWrapper Out-Default `
-Begin {
    $cachedOutput = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
} `
-Process {
    if($_ -ne $null) { $null = $cachedOutput.Add($_) }
    while($cachedOutput.Count -gt 500) { $cachedOutput.RemoveAt(0) }
} `
-End {
    $uniqueOutput = $cachedOutput | Foreach-Object {
        $_.GetType().FullName } | Select -Unique

    $containsInterestingTypes = ($uniqueOutput -notcontains `
    "System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord") -and
    ($uniqueOutput -notlike `
    "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.*")

    if(($cachedOutput.Count -gt 0) -and $containsInterestingTypes)
    {
        $GLOBAL:ll = $cachedOutput | % { $_ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Link to the [Author's Blog](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/category/guide/). source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/LeeHolmes/PowerShellCookbook/blob/master/PowerShellCookbook.psm1)

Answer (score 0):

A less obscure alternative to overriding the `Out-Default` cmdlet for implicit `Out-File` calls is to wrap the commands of interest in a *script block* (`{ ... }`) and pipe its invocation (`&`) to a *single* `Out-File` call.

Unless you need to control the output encoding, you can then even use `>`, `Out-File`'s effective alias.

```bsh
& {

  # ... Put the commands of interest here; e.g.:

  'hi'

  Get-Item /

  Get-Date 

  # ...

} > $LogFile  
# If you need to control the output encoding, use
# `| Out-File $LogFile -Encoding ...` instead of `> $LogFile`
```

On a general note: files created with `>` / `Out-File` capture *for-display* representations that aren't generally suitable for *programmatic processing*.